# QGraphicsItem collision jitter/tremble

Tags: c++, qt, collision, qgraphicsitem

Hello guys I need your help,

I'm creating a timeline like widget in Qt based on the QGraphics framework. My problem is to handle collisions of items (inherited from QGraphicsRectItem) in my Timeline tracks.

I use the itemChange() function to keep track of the collisions. To keep the items in the parent boundingRect I use the following code wich works like a charm

```
if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene())
   if (thisRect.intersects(parentRect)) {
        const QPointF offset(mapFromParent(thisRect.topLeft()));
        QPointF newPos(value.toPointF());

        if (snapToGrid) {
            newPos.setX(floor(qMin(parentRect.right() - offset.x() - thisRect.width(),
                                   qMax(newPos.x(), parentRect.left() / 2 - offset.x())) / (snapValue * pxPerSec(duration))) * snapValue * pxPerSec(duration));
        }
        else {             
            newPos.setX(qMin(parentRect.right() - offset.x() - thisRect.width(),
                             qMax(newPos.x(), parentRect.left() - offset.x())));
        }

        newPos.setY(parentItem()->boundingRect().height() * 0.1);
        return newPos;
    }
}
```

This stops the items immediately if they reach the left or right boundary of my timline tracks, even if I move the mouse outside my view/scene. It's like an invisible wall.
Now I want the same behaviour if one item in a track collides with another.

```
const QRectF parentRect(parentItem()->sceneBoundingRect());
const QRectF thisRect(sceneBoundingRect());

    foreach (QGraphicsItem *qgitem, collidingItems()) {
        TimelineItem *item = qgraphicsitem_cast<TimelineItem *>(qgitem);
        QPointF newPos(value.toPointF());

        if (item) {
            const QRectF collideRect = item->sceneBoundingRect();
            const QPointF offset(mapFromParent(thisRect.topLeft()));

            if (thisRect.intersects(collideRect) && thisRect.x() < collideRect.x()) {
                newPos.setX(collideRect.left() - offset.x() - thisRect.width());
            }

            if (thisRect.intersects(collideRect) && thisRect.x() > collideRect.x()) {
                newPos.setX(collideRect.right() + offset.x());
            }

        }

        newPos.setY(parentItem()->boundingRect().height() * 0.1);
        return newPos;
    }
```

The problem is that if I move an item via mouse against another item you see them intersecting/overlapping and then the item I moved snaps back to the minimum not intersecting distance. How do I manage to stop the moving item immediately if it hits another (no trembling forth and back movement intersecting thing). Just like the way the items are kept in parents boundingRect (first code block), the invisible wall like behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with "thisRect". If you're calling this from an ItemPositionChange, then sceneBoundingRect is returning the bounding rectangle of the item in its previous position, not the new one. What happens is that the current position succeeds even though though there's a collision, but the next one fails because you're always checking the previous results, and then it snaps back to avoid the collision.

After getting the local item's scene rectangle, you'll need to translate it to the new future position of the item:

```
QPointF new_pos (value.toPointF ());
QRectF thisRect (sceneBoundingRect());
thisRect.translate (new_pos - pos());
```

I've moved the creation of "new_pos" outside the loop so that it's available for the rectangle translation. It's also faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, good point but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are any of these items parented? If so, then you have a mix of coordinate systems, i.e. "newPos" and "offset" are in parent coordinates, but "thisRect" and "collideRect" are in scene coordinates. If they're not parented, then it's all scene coordinates, and in that case, I think this looks correct. If there are parent items involved, use mapToScene instead of mapToParent and then also map newPos to scene coordinates for all comparisons and adjustments, and then back to parent coordinates before returning.

Comment: The items are parented to a track item but it has the same width as the scene and it's rect is also set to (0,0). So the x, y origin should be the same.

Comment: Removed the "offset" but still the same behaviour. EDIT: added a gif in the first post.